# c# - is this code possible?

Tags: c#, command, constants

I play a game which I have a c# written source to, and I'm trying to make a command. Say I have these constants:

```
public class Flags {
    public const ulong
        Normal = 0x0,
        FlashingName = 0x1,
        Dizzy = 1UL << 58,
        DivineShield = 1UL << 57,
        Poisoned = 0x2
}
```

And I want to try a command like this:

```
case "addflag":{
    client.Entity.AddTopStatus(Update.Flags.(Data[1]), DateTime.Now.AddDays(1), false);
    break;
}
```

Where in game I would type @addflag Dizzy (dizzy in place of (data[1]) in the constants), kind of like if the command was:

```
client.Entity.AddTopStatus(Update.Flags.Dizzy, DateTime.Now.AddDays(1), false);
```

but since the (data[1]) is there, I can do it by command, rather than calling it directly. I can choose any constant, rather than calling out each one seperately.

This code I get an error in, but that was expected. Is there someway I can do this? (i hope you guys are understanding me, im not very good with c# so sorry if this is confusing)

Comment: Flags looks more like it should be an `Enum` (although thats a lot of different type of items from what I can tell), in which case it becomes a question of how to get enum key by name..

Answer (score 0):

Make `Flags` an `enum` and then use [Enum.Parse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/essfb559(v=vs.110).aspx) to convert  `data[1]` to the appropriate flag.

```
public enum Flags : ulong 
{

        Normal = 0x0,
        FlashingName = 0x1,
        Dizzy = 1UL << 58,
        DivineShield = 1UL << 57,
        Poisoned = 0x2
}
```